# «Custom price» из произвольного поля товаров

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Скажите пожалуйста, если данный код считывает цену из произвольного поля товара у которого id=96 и заносит, для каждого товара, в корзину именно эту цену:

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) {
    $rrp = get_post_meta( 96, 'rrp_price', true );
    $custom_price = $rrp; 
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price); 
  }}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10 );
```

Как можно реализовать вариант чтобы цена считывалась и попадала в корзину из произвольного поля для каждого товара СВОЯ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object, $id_field, $price_field ) {
    $rrp = get_post_meta( (int)$id_field, $price_field, true );
    $custom_price = $rrp; 
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price); 
}}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10 );
```

Только нужны проверки на валидность данных

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67743/discussion-on-answer-by-daemonhk-custom-price----).

Answer (score 1):

Попытка внедрить таким образом не увенчалась успехом

```
function add_custom_price( $cart_object, $id_field, $price, $price_field ) {

$price_field = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rrp_price', true );
$custom_price = get_post_meta( (int)$id_field, 'rrp_price', true );

      if( $price_field = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'rrp_price', true ) ){
        $price = $price_field;
    }

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
       $cart_item['data']->set_price($custom_price);   
    }
    return $price;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 10 );
```

Warning: Missing argument (2,3,4) - в этом вся соль?

Comment: в add_action надо добавить еще один параметр - 4 (кол-во аргументов у add_custom_price). Иначе в add_custom_price передается только один.